# Convert hh:mm to minutes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have data coming from a source system which sends time in hh:mm nvarchar format. I am trying to convert it into minutes. I only want to do this in SSRS Report as per the need. So, I am looking for a SSRS Expression rather than T-SQL.

Here is how my data looks like:

```
10:00
-2:00
-11:30
```

Expected Output:

```
600
-120
-690
```

Here is what I tried so far but looking for a better/performance efficient way

```
SUM(CInt(LEFT(Replace(Fields!HHMM.Value, "-", ""),InStrRev(Replace(Fields!HHMM.Value, "-", ""),":")-1))*60 + 
CInt(RIGHT(Replace(Fields!HHMM.Value, "-", ""),InStrRev(Replace(Fields!HHMM.Value, "-", ""),":")))
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are there too many possible values to use a lookup table? It would be very fast.

Comment: Yes! There might be more than one value.

Comment: Too many possible values would be in the range of perhaps >10,000,000. [Report Builder Functions - Lookup Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Oh! No. Only a handful of values. But, since this is an adhoc report, I am not sure if its worth to use a lookup table as this is more of giving cosmetic look to the data.

Comment: You wrote "looking for a better/performance efficient way". A lookup table would give you that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something similar to what forpas did in SSRS syntax.

```
=LEFT(Fields!TIME.Value, INSTR(Fields!TIME.Value, ":") - 1) * 60 + 
    IIF(LEFT(Fields!TIME.Value, 1) = "-", -1, 1) * 
    MID(Fields!TIME.Value, INSTR(Fields!TIME.Value, ":") + 1, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be little better than what I tried. I've added my response as well to my original post.

Comment: I just verified the data again and your code doesn't seem to be putting the negative sign if there is one.

Comment: I tried it in a text box and `11:30` ends up with `-690` so it seems to be working. Is your data different - maybe spaces in it? You wrap the LEFT and MID functions in a INT() function to try to resolve spaces.

Comment: No, there are no spaces in my data.

Answer (score 1):

With string functions and casting to integer:

```
select
  cast(left(timecol, charindex(':', timecol) - 1) as int) * 60 +
  case when left(timecol, 1) = '-' then -1 else 1 end *
  cast(substring(timecol, charindex(':', timecol) + 1, len(timecol)) as int)
from tablename
```

or without casting by implicit conversions to integer:

```
select
  left(timecol, charindex(':', timecol) - 1) * 60 +
  case when left(timecol, 1) = '-' then -1 else 1 end *
  substring(timecol, charindex(':', timecol) + 1, len(timecol))
from tablename
```

Replace `timecol` with the actual name of the column.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a22ac3603b5457ccb2e00a1d1f3527ad).
Results:

```
 600
-120
-690
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas! But as mentioned in my question, I am looking for an SSRS solution not SQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can do what you want:

In `TSQL`:

```
select (case when CONVERT(integer,Replace('-11:30',':','')) < 0 then -1 else 1 end ) * ((DATEPART(HOUR,CONVERT(Datetime,Replace('-11:30','-',''))) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(Datetime,Replace('-11:30','-',''))))
```

**EDIT:**

You can translate the `TSQL` Query I posted to something like this to use it in `SSRS` (please note that I did not test the `SSRS` code):

```
Switch(Cint(Replace(Fields!timeField.Value,":","")) < 0,-1,Cint(Replace(Fields!timeField.Value,":","")) >= 0,1) * ((Hour(cdate(Replace(Fields!timeField.Value,":",""))) * 60 ) + Minute(cdate(Replace(Fields!timeField.Value,":",""))))
```

Comment: Thanks @Karamafrooz! But as mentioned in my question, I am looking for an SSRS solution not SQL solution.

Comment: @Julaayi Sorry, I did'nt notice that, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use Scalar function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_To_Min
(
    @timeVar nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    declare @op char(1) = SUBSTRING(@timeVar, 1, 1)
    if(@op = '-')
    begin
        set @timeVar = SUBSTRING(@timeVar, 2, LEN(@timeVar))
    end
    else
        set @op = ''

    declare @time time = CONVERT( TIME, @timeVar )

    declare @h int = DATEPART(hh, @time)
    declare @m int = DATEPART(Minute, @time)

    RETURN CONVERT(int, CONCAT(@op, (@h * 60) + @m))

END
```

**Call**

```
SELECT fn_To_Min('10:25'), col1, col2, ...
```

Comment: Thank you but I am only looking for a SSRS expression not SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what that worked in my case which also handles (null) values in SSRS.

```
IIF(Left(Fields!TIME.Value, 1) = "-", "-", "") &  
Right("000" & CInt(Replace(LEFT(Replace(Fields!TIME.Value, "-", ""), (INSTR(Replace(Fields!TIME.Value, "-", ""), ":"))), ":", "")) * 60 + 

CInt(IIF(IsNumeric(MID(Fields!TIME.Value, INSTR(Fields!TIME.Value, ":") + 1, 10)), 
                    MID(Fields!TIME.Value, INSTR(Fields!TIME.Value, ":") + 1, 10), 
                    Nothing
        ))
, 3)
```